# Why  does my MacBook Pro's keyboard freeze when it wakes up so I have to hard reboot?

Tags: macos, keyboard, sleep-wake

Sometimes, but not every time, when I open my MacBook Pro to wake it from sleep, the keyboard doesn't respond, so I have to reboot my Mac using the power button.

There's a good chance that it happens when I close the lid without the laptop being plugged into power (the MagSafe plug), then plug in either power or headphones before I wake the computer again.

It is a [MacBook Pro 15"(2011)](http://store.apple.com/cn/configure/MD318CH/A), 2.2Ghz Intel Core i7, 500GB 5400 RPM, 8G RAM running
Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50d). I have zh-CN ([PRC Chinese](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/I18N__LangTags__List5.8.9.3pm.html)) (Mainland China, simplified characters) as the preferred language for all users by default. I upgraded my Lion one by one (from 10.7 to 10.7.1,... till 10.7.3) and while upgrading, I didn't get any error or alert. So the updates went well.

I tried to solve it following a work around involving inserting and unplugging my headphones, but that didn't work out.

Is there any solid solution, or is this a known MacBook Pro issue?

Comment: nobody meet same thing with me?

Comment: When it freezes: does the mouse/trackpad work? Does an external keyboard work? What does the external sleep light on the front do when this is happening? And, next time this happens, can you try re-closing the lid and then re-opening it and tell us what happens and what the sleep light does?

Comment: @CajunLuke mouse/teackpad can work; external keybaord not test,in home i just usage pure Laptop; sleep light/the feont logo light always bright; i try re-closing lid,and re-open, the problem not change,and notice,when i re-closing lid,the sleep light/front logo all brighting... so means hardware is locked...

Comment: So the sleep light stays bright the whole time through the open/close/open with no pulsing? And the Apple logo on the backside of the screen stays lit? What if you close the lid for a long period of time - is there any change?

Comment: after keyboard die, reclose/reopen, and waiting long time, things not changed... i wait 2min...

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue with a brand new Retina MacBook Pro. I think it's a software fault actually, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @NickWiggill have you tried  http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1559?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking the laptop into your local Apple Store or an Apple Authorized repair location. This definitely seems like a hardware fault: I would hope they'd replace or repair the laptop. Make sure you make a complete backup before you go to the store.

Comment: thanx ,this is one can try way...